# Angular FormControls Always Valid When More Than One In Form

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have two inputs that use FormControl that always show as valid but if I take one out then the remaining will be valid/invalid as expected. I would change the two formcontrols out for one ControlGroup but 1.) I want to understand what I'm doing wrong and 2.) I need to access one formcontrol for an autocomplete I have in the component.

Relevant HTML:

```
<form 
    fxLayout="column" 
    fxLayoutAlign="center center" 
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(status, count)" 
    #statusForm="ngForm"
>

    <!-- Status Input -->
    <div>
        <mat-form-field>
        <input 
            matInput placeholder="Status" 
            [formControl]="statusFormControl"
            [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            [(ngModel)]="status"
            name="status"
            required
        >
        <mat-error *ngIf="statusFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Status is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let status of filteredStatusList | async" [value]="status.name">
        {{ status.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    </div>


    <!-- Count Input -->
    <mat-form-field>
        <input 
            matInput placeholder="Count" 
            [formControl]="countFormControl"
            type="number"
            min="1"
            [(ngModel)]="count"
            name="count"
            required
        >
        <mat-error *ngIf="countFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Count must be a <strong>number</strong>
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    {{statusForm.valid}}
    {{statusForm.invalid}}

    <button 
        mat-raised-button color="primary" 
        *ngIf="statusForm.valid" 
        type="submit" 
        [disabled]="statusForm.invalid"
    >
        Add
    </button>
```

and TS:

```
export class ... {

statusFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required
]);

countFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required
]);

...

constructor() {
this.filteredStatusList = this.statusFormControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(status => status ? this.filterStatusList(status) : this.allStatuses.slice())
  );

}

filterStatusList(statusName: string) {
return this.allStatuses.filter(status =>
  status.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(statusName.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}

}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is causing your problem ... but it is highly recommended that we use template driven forms OR reactive forms ... not both. Currently you are using both. You have the `new FormControl` in the code in addition to the `ngModel` in the template. Consider removing the `ngModel` and just use reactive forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what one of mine looks like using reactive forms (see below). Notice the form's `formGroup` directive. And I used the `formControlName` directive instead of the `formControl` directive ... but either would work.

**HTML**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal"
          novalidate
          (ngSubmit)="save()"
          [formGroup]="customerForm">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                       for="firstNameId">First Name</label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="firstNameId" 
                           type="text" 
                           placeholder="First Name (required)" 
                           formControlName="firstName" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                    for="lastNameId">Last Name</label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="lastNameId" 
                           type="text" 
                           placeholder="Last Name (required)" 
                           formControlName="lastName" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**Component Class**

```
customerForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]]
    });

}
```

Also, if you need to reference one of the FormControls using the syntax above, you can do so like this:

```
this.customerForm.get('lastName')
```

Your method would then look something like this:

```
this.filteredStatusList = this.myForm.get('status').valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(status => status ? this.filterStatusList(status) : this.allStatuses.slice())
  );
```